# Get sending status on calling Gmail Intent in android

Tags: android, gmail

For sending a mail through the default Gmail intent of the device and I am using the following function:

```
private void initShareIntent(String type) {
        boolean found = false;
        Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("text/plain");
        share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

        // gets the list of intents that can be loaded.
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(
                share, 0);
        if (!resInfo.isEmpty()) {
            for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {

                if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains(type)
                        || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains(type)) {
                    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                            "Reg:xxx");
                    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareText);
                    share.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                return;
            }
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Select"));
        }
    }
```

and calling the function like this:

```
initShareIntent("mail");
```

Is there a way to get the sending status of this action(success or failure)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get the sending status of this action(success or failure)?

No, sorry. You do not even know if the user actually sent the email.

Beyond that, your overall approach to this is awful. Rather than simply using `ACTION_SEND` and allowing the user to choose how they wish to send this text, you limit them to some random app that has `mail` in the package name and supports `ACTION_SEND` of `text/plain`. The flaws in this are simply stunning:

- You assume that all email apps have `mail` in their package name, where spending a few minutes examining the Play Store would demonstrate that this is incorrect
- You assume that the last app with `mail` in the package name is the right one, even if that is not an app that the user actually uses (e.g., is installed on the device but is not configured)
- You assume that the user actually wants to send this by email

My guess, given your subject line (`"Reg:Clock In Clock Out"`), is that you are trying to send an email to somebody for the purposes of timesheet management. In that case, here are your primary options, in descending order of validity:

1. Don't use email, but submit the timesheet via a Web service
2. Use email, but have a Web service send it, so that you know that it is sent
3. Use email, but use JavaMail to send it, so that you know that it is sent
4. Use `ACTION_SENDTO` and a `mailto:` `Uri`, as presumably this timesheet information is supposed to go to a particular email account, not anyone the user might pick from their contact list, as this not only will set the destination address but will automatically limit the user to email apps supporting `mailto:` `Uri` schemes
5. Use `ACTION_SEND` and get rid of your flawed filtering mechanism, just allowing the user to choose the right app, and get rid of `createChooser()` so that they can make their choice the default for use in the future

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions.. The requirement is to send the message through Gmail(and that wasn't any random app) .. So I can't simply call the ACTION_SEND you see. Is there a better way to call GMail. And I knew what I asked wasn't possible but needed to show some proof.. Initially the requirement was just to open up the mail intent, but now they want a toast message

Comment: @Lincy: "The requirement is to send the message through Gmail" -- whoever established the requirement needs to be fired.